# I need help positioning my buttons on my site! HTML

Tags: html, button

I have a button and if i click on it, it redirects me to a different page.

Here is the code for my button:

```
<form method="get" action="MY BUTTON LINK.html">
<button type="submit" align="middle">TEXT ON BUTTON</button></form>
```

I wish to have many of these in a row (one below the other) going down the left hand side of my page. By default they are on the right and i use `<p>` tags to make sure they are positioned one under another, but the information that is usually in the center is moved downwards below the button. What i want is for the buttons to go down the left hand side while the information is still in the center. I have achieved this with an image using align="left" but it either doesn't work with the buttons or i am not placing it in the code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well to begin with, your PHP is not being used correctly and is unnecessary.  Try putting this in your HTML file:

```
    <body>
    <style type="text/CSS">
    #buttons {
    display: inline;
    }
    </style>
    <ul id="buttons">
    <li><a href="****"><button value="hello">hello</button></a></li>
    <li><a href="****"><button value="hello">hello</button></a></li>
    <li><a href="****"><button value="hello">hello</button></a></li>
    </ul>
    </body>
```

note: replace the **** with a URL you want to be redirected to